# Biblioteca de Clases para Controles C#

Tags: c#

Deseo saber si hay una forma de crear un **bliblioteca de clases**, que **interactue con ciertos "controles"**; es decir que en dicha clase pueda **modificar las propiedades de por ejemplo... un textbox**. Esto con el fin de establecer algunos **formatos predeterminados** y **no tener que estar diseñando una forma cada vez que inicio un proyecto nuevo.

Lo he intentado, pero siempre ha sido con una clase dentro de un proyecto que ya contiene una forma.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una alternativa a lo que estás consultando pueden ser plantillas de proyectos para crear proyectos con elementos predeterminados o plantillas de elementos para elementos que deben tener ciertas propiedades. Estos te permiten incluso añadirles eventos al nuevo control que puede tener varios controles incluidos.

A continuación de docs microsoft donde explica cómo crear estos elementos.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-custom-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

Puedes diseñar tu propia biblioteca de clases para diseñar tus propios controles y luego añadirla a tus proyectos, también puedes diseñarlos en base a otros controles ya existentes.

> Archivo>Nuevo Proyecto>Biblioteca de clases

Comment: Descrubri que hay una biblioteca de clases exclusiva para formas.